# is there a way to include a script to fancybox content?

Tags: javascript, fancybox

i'm trying to include a script to fancy box however it doesn't work.

```
$("#addmsg").click(function () {
    var msg = '<script type="text/javascript" src="/1.js"></script>'; 
    $.fancybox({
      'content': msg});
});
```

but a msg like this do work:

```
    var msg = '<script>function foo(){alert("this works");}</script>';      
    msg += '<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="foo()"/>';
```

now the script i want to include is huge and i can't write every line of it in quotation marks.

is there anyway to make it work? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.
in my html file i added the button:
`<button id="addmsg" href="#addmsg_div">ADD</button>`

the tag `#addmsg_div` contains my intended msg. in my .js file i wrote:
`$("#addmsg").fancybox();`

Answer (score 0):

This might work!

```
$("#addmsg").click(function () {
    $.fancybox({ 'href': "http://mydomain.com/folder/pageLoaded.html"});
});
```

pageLoaded.html ---

```
   <html>
     <body>
      <input id="clicker" type='button' value='Cancel' />
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/1.js"></script>
<!-- OR -->
      <script>
       $("body").on("click", "#clicker", function(){
         alert("This Works");
       });
      </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```